# How to integrate multivariable function with arguments like tx and ty?

Tags: calculus

$D_{2}f_{1} = D_{1}f_{2}$

$f_{1}(x,y),f_{2}(x,y)$ are both $C^{1}$

$f(x,y,t) = xf_{1}(tx,ty) + yf_{2}(tx,ty)$

The problem is to prove that $\partial \over\partial y$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y,t)dt = f_{2}(x,y) $

I don`t know how to deal with integration of the function with the arguments like 'tx' how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since $t$ is passed into $f_{1}(x,y)$ and $f_{2}(x,y)$ alongside $x$ and $y$, you can integrate each part of the function twice, first with respect to $x$ for $f_{1}(x,y)$, and first with respect to $y$ for $f_{2}(x,y)$.